# Powershell EncodedCommand Length Issue

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell.exe's -EncodedCommand parameter to run a powershell script as a different user.  I'm doing this to avoid dealing with command line difficulties of escaping quotes and other special characters.  I've found that when the length of the encoded command exceeds 916 characters, it fails with the following message:

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The stub received bad data.
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$path = 'c:\temp'

$UserName = '.\someuser'
$Password = 'somepassword'
$securePassword = ($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName, $securePassword

$command = {& .\Restore-DatabaseFromBackupFile.ps1 -DatabaseName 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseBackupFilePath 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseDataLogicalName 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseLogLogicalName 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseDataFilePath 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef' -DatabaseLogFilePath 'a';Start-Sleep -Seconds 2}
$commandBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($commandBytes)
Write-Warning $encodedCommand.Length
Write-Warning $encodedCommand
Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand" -WorkingDirectory $path -LoadUserProfile -Credential $Credential
```

This code will fail.  However, if you remove a single character from any of the parameter values (or shorten the command within the script block in any way), it will execute successfully.

I've found references to there being an 8190 character limit to cmd.exe on Windows XP and newer (this is running on Windows Server 2012 R2), but I seem to be a long way from this limit.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE1: This behavior is affected by the -Credential parameter.  If I remove the -Credential parameter and run as the current user, I've been able to successfully execute the command when the encoded command length is over 19,000.

**UPDATE2: @Xalorous's comments did solve the issue. Setting the ExecutionPolicy to Bypass.  I would be happy to give credit if he/she would post the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` instead of Unrestricted.  Unrestricted makes sense for setting machine or user policy, local or GPO.  It makes less sense for the commandline.

Comment: If you figured out your problem, please post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I didn't figure out my problem, but I think @Xalorous did.  When I made that change I was able to run it interactively in a powershell window successfully.  I'm actually trying to make this work through the Azure Custom Script Extension, and am still having the same issue.  However, the Xalorous's suggestion seems to be the right answer for the question I posted.  How do I properly give credit?

Comment: I was guessing, and unable to test to verify yes/no on my suggestion, so I added it as a comment.  I copied it below to an answer

Comment: It may be that changing from 'Unrestricted' to 'Bypass' worked simply because the latter has fewer characters.

Comment: @RyanBemrose: The execution policy was not part of the encoded command, so I don't believe that would factor in to it.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -ExecutionPolicy Bypass instead of Unrestricted. Unrestricted makes sense for setting machine or user policy, local or GPO. It makes less sense for the commandline

Answer (score 0):

In both Powershell 5.1 and Powershell 7.2 Start-Process cannot pass in large command line arguments like powershell -EncodedCommands when the -Credentials are provided.

As a work around, reduce the Start-Powershell arguments size.

Use a working directory where both the parent and target credentials have read and write permissions to the directory.

Write the powershell encoded command to a temporary file
Execute the file
Write the output to a file
Import the File
Clean up Temporary files

```
$syntax = @"
.\Restore-DatabaseFromBackupFile.ps1 -DatabaseName 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseBackupFilePath 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseDataLogicalName 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseLogLogicalName 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' -DatabaseDataFilePath 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef' -DatabaseLogFilePath 'a';Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
"@
$workingFolder = 'c:\sharedFolder'
$workingScriptPath = [IO.Path]::Combine($workingFolder,  [IO.Path]::GetFileName([IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()) + '.ps1')
$workinFolderStdOut =  [IO.Path]::Combine($workingFolder,  [IO.Path]::GetFileName([IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()) + '.cilxml')

Set-Content -LiteralPath $workingScriptPath -Value $syntax -Encoding UTF8
Start-Process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList "-NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -OutputFormat XML -File `"$workingScriptPath`"" -Credential $Credential -WorkingDirectory $workinFolderStdOut -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput $workinFolderStdOut -Wait
Import-Clixml -Path $workinFolderStdOut
```